# SQL Rank does not work as expected

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rank, cross-apply

Im trying to use SQL function Rank() to get a list the top records of several groups. Here is what im tring that does not work :

```
select hc.hId, hc.DpId, hc.Rank 
from (
    select d.hId, DpId, Rank()
        OVER (Partition by DpId ORDER BY d.hId) AS Rank
    FROM CurDp d
    INNER JOIN HostList h on d.DpId = h.hId
    INNER JOIN Coll_hList pch on d.hId = pch.hId
    where h.Model = 'PRIMARY'  
) hc where hc.Rank <= 10
```

I get the top 10 records as follows :

```
 HId    | DpId | Rank
 -------x------x------
  7     | 590  | 1
  18    | 590  | 2
  23    | 590  | 3
  24    | 590  | 4
  26    | 590  | 5
  36    | 590  | 6
  63    | 590  | 7
  80    | 590  | 8
  84    | 590  | 9
  88    | 590  | 10
```

But when I use CROSS APPLY, which the function I need because i have to get that kind of records on different models, I use this code :

```
select pch.hId, cc.DpId, cc.Rank from from Coll_hList pch
cross apply
(
    select hc.hId, hc.DpId, hc.Rank 
    from (
        select d.hId, DpId, Rank()
            OVER (Partition by DpId ORDER BY d.hId) AS Rank
        FROM CurrDp d
        INNER JOIN HostList h on d.DpId = h.hId
        where h.Model = 'PRIMARY' and d.hId = pch.hId
    ) hc where hc.Rank <= 10
) cc
```

Here, I get always rank 1, and it doesn't filter anything (not showing the whole result) :

```
HId    | DpId | Rank
-------x------x------
7        590    1
18       590    1
23       590    1
24       590    1
26       590    1
36       590    1
63       590    1
80       590    1
84       590    1
88       590    1
124      590    1
125      590    1
133      590    1
```

Am I doing it wrong ? Is it because of CROSS APPLY ?

I also used dense_rank() instead of rank(), but it shows the same result.

Any help to achieve this request with CROSS APPLY would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, you join on `Coll_hList` and get a result set of more than 10 entries which then are ranked.

In the second case, in your apply-sub-select, you only create a one-entry result set. Ranking of that results in rank one.

Your ranking has to be done in the outer statement:

```
select pch.hId, cc.DpId, Rank()
            OVER (Partition by cc.DpId ORDER BY cc.hId) AS Rank 
from  Coll_hList pch
cross apply
(
        select d.hId, DpId
        FROM CurrDp d
        INNER JOIN HostList h on d.DpId = h.hId
        where h.Model = 'PRIMARY' and d.hId = pch.hId

) cc
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, that works great. I just did not understand your "one-entry result set". Do you mean the ranking method sees only one result that cant be sorted ?

Comment: Exactly. The cross apply syntax creates some kind of "temporary table" for each row of the result set computed by previously executed joins (at least it helps thinking of it that way) which then is joined with only that specific row. In your case the temporary tables only have one row.